# "No sitemap linked in your robots.txt file"

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

Relatively new to anything that doesn't require common sense in WordPress. My previous site was built poorly etc, so cutting a long story short I installed a new theme and started building up pages again etc.

I have ran various diagnostics on seo etc while I am working and seem to have problems with indexability and sitemaps.

Getting this message on the onpage.org site check and had something similar on another platform wherby it is saying there are resources that are restricted from indexing.

Please help asap as i have good rankings and don't want this to affect the next crawl.

Comment: sitemaps are convenience, not a necessity. By default wordpress do not generate such because it is pointless on any good structure theme, with a good navigetability in the content/menus. If you feel like you have to have a sitemap, you should use one of the sitemaps plugins

Answer (score 1):

Well, that message is pretty self explanatory. There is no sitemap linked in your `robots.txt` file. So you check if you have a sitemap (if not install a plugin that will generate one for you) and add this line to your robots.txt file in the root of your site:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know if you already has a sitemap. If no, I suggest you install [YOAST SEO](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin to manage your sitemaps.

With Yoast, your sitemap has this link:
http://domain.com/sitemap_index.xml

Then, add your sitemap to your robots.txt file, like that:

```
Sitemap: http://domain.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

If you already have a sitemap without Yoast, the step is the same. Just add the sitemap URL to your robots.txt like line above.

About your comment:

> Please help asap as i have good rankings and don't want this to affect the next crawl

A sitemap is only a file to help crawlers to find your pages. But, if your new pages are linked in other pages of your site (like homepage), crawlers you identify your new pages same way.

Then, don't worry with this alert. There are many other important things to consider when we talk about SEO, like good content, legibility content, **page speed** and mobile navigation (responsive and amp).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Yoast Tool, Edit Files to create and modify the robots.text.

[Wordpress Robot.txt tutorial](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-robots-txt/)

Then, yes, add

```
Sitemap: https://domain.com/sitemap_index.xml
```